# Why does dimensionality reduction improve unsupervised clustering performance of movie posters?

Tags: cluster-analysis, conv-neural-network, cosine-similarity, unsupervised-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I am writing a paper where I am trying to cluster movie posters based on their visual features. The goal is to cluster movie posters which look similar.

To get a quantitative description of how posters "look", I have extracted 25088 features for all posters using the pre trained VGG16 CNN. These features are stored in a matrix with the dimensions (*# movie posters, 25088*).

Based on the extracted features I want to:

1. Create buckets/clusters of similar movie posters which can be drawn from in a recommendation scenario.
2. Get a list of *n* most similar posters to a a given poster (e.g. *n* most similar posters to the poster of Madagascar).

The clustering algorithm I will be using is *K-means* and I have evaluated the quality of the clustering using the *Silhouette Coefficient*.

I have tried the following:

- Clustering using the raw features with *K-means* (using cosine similarity)
- Doing PCA (10 components) before clustering
- Doing NMF (10 components) before clustering
- Calculating a similarity matrix to be able to get a list of *n* most similar movie posters.

I am trying to find the best and most simple solution. Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Using PCA and NMF results in a higher *Silhouette Coefficient* (respectively 0.2 and .35) compared to .01 on the raw data. Is that because a lot of the variance is discarded through PCA and NMF? I am concerned that this is the case, as the Silhouette Coefficient goes up, as I decrease the number of components in both PCA and NMF.
2. To get a list of n most similar posters, I have calculated a similarity matrix from where I print the movies with the highest cosine similarity to a given movie. Is there a way to do this without calculating a similarity matrix? It seems to me that this should be possible using the information in the output matrices from PCA and NMF.

Answer (score 0):

You must not compare Silhouette computed on different data.

But you can compute Silhouette using the original data every time, and only use the cluster labels found in projected data. But it will likely be equally bad, because of the curse of dimensionality.

Why cosine? It's overused, you should have a good argument to use it.

PCA tries to preserve variance, not angles. So cosine and PCA are applicable in different situations.

Comment: Okay, you are right. When computing the Silhouette score on the original data, the score is equally close to zero for both PCA and NMF. But is it just not possible to cluster images when you have a high number of features?

I used cosine similarity as it used in many applications when dealing with text or images. However, you are right, I don't have a good argument.

Comment: Cosine is not less susceptible problems of high dimensionality. It works okay on high dimensional text because most values there are 0 anyway. But in your case, the input data probably is not sparse.

Comment: Actually the data is sparse. Why do cosine work better with this kind of data?

Comment: Because it's faster to compute with lots of zeros.